# installing tp link tl-wn822n on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 18.04, tp-link

okay so im having some issues. im very new to linux at this point ive only used it for about a day. and i bought a tp link wifi adapter for better internet. while ubuntu seems to notice it and connect through it, im having a lot of trouble downloading and installing drivers. the guide they give seems to have incomplete commands for me to follow along with in terminal and the only drivers im getting are a folder with some text files and code. i was kind of following it until it told me to compile the drivers by going into the driver directory. i don't know were whats installing to. please i dont want to bother people but im totally lost and i don't want to feel like i just wasted 30 dollars on a hunk of broken plastic. and so far ive only seen threads about it on ubuntu 14 and 16.

also im very sorry for not giving you the wireless info script. terminal keeps telling me its unable to resolve host adress, this is also not a connection problem its a speed problem. installing the drivers as ive been told dont work. i get a bunch of error messages. when installing things like sudo apt-get install rtl8192cu-dkms terminal tells me it is unable to locate the package. there's supposed to be a chip.ko file in the directory but i dont see any chip.ko file or any new file names from what comes in the base download. 
***edit: the kernal version for ubuntu 18 is too new to work with this device. 
please stop flagging this as a duplicate when the threads talking about this device do not address any of these issues.***

Comment: The TP Link instructions are a bit vague. You download the driver ZIP file and unzip it. This will create a new directory with all the necessary files in it. Then you do `cd ` into that new directory and enter commands like 'make clean' and 'make'.

Comment: thank you! youve helped me along but i seem to have hit another road block. now its telling me there are errors while doing the make command. the guide say's there's also a chip.ko file that should be names but i see no such file in there. im assuming i need to to run the insomod command to check if the driver installed correctly

Comment: There should be no errors at any stage or you won't get a driver file. What does the error say exactly? Did you install `gcc`?

Comment: i did 
[link] linux_v4.3.15_14701.20150715_BTCOEX20150615-41/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/suzume/Desktop/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.3.15_14701.20150715_BTCOEX20150615-41/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
Makefile:1551: recipe for target '_module_/home/suzume/Desktop/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.3.15_14701.20150715_BTCOEX20150615-41' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/suzume/Desktop/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.3.15_14701.20150715_BTCOEX20150615-41] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-43-generic'
Makefile:1696: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2

Comment: ive tried that one and i end up with the same problem. nothing installed and no were to understand how or why

Comment: @suzumetin The real error is not in there. I think the script failed earlier. Can you paste the whole output of the `make` command into the question, or put it up on `pastebin.com` and link to it?

Comment: can do! https://pastebin.com/GMWA4GSi

Comment: There you go. Line 4: `please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel`. Use `apt policy libelf-dev`, etc., to find out which of these three packages is suitable for your system. Then do `sudo apt install [package]` and try again.

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lsmod | grep cfg`

Comment: There are three versions of this device. It is not at all clear which you have. Please insert the device and run: `lsusb` Next, edit your question to add the result. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: The duplicate tell you to do the exact same thing with newer source code, so what is different?  Voting to leave closed.

Comment: no it does not i have look through it and it dose not tell me to put in any of these commands
git clone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
make

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got another answer for you which I just tested and it appears to be working on my real system. I just don't have the USB device to test it on.

Follow these steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
make
```

My compilation went smooth with no errors and I ended with `8192eu.ko`

If you compilation went without any errors, you should have that file. Next, to test it (temporarily), just do this (save your work before this step).

```
sudo insmod 8192eu.ko
lsmod | grep 8192eu
```

You should see:

```
8192eu               1110016  0
cfg80211              622592  4 8192eu,iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
```

Test your device, if it works, we'll add it on start-up. As it is, it only works on-demand. If you get errors, post them here and we'll try to resolve them.

Comment: it worked damn near perfectly! i can actually run a ookla speedtest with out a latencey error.
although i did get one error suzume@suzume-G751JY:~/rtl8192eu-linux-driver$ sudo insmod 8192eu.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module 8192eu.ko: File exists
 and that was it other wise it worked exactly as you said

Comment: Ok great we are nearly there, second last step, can you please check whether file `/etc/rc.local` exists? `ls -l /etc/rc.local` and if so, tell us its permissions please. Do `ls -l /etc/rc.local` and post its output.

Comment: Thanks, this solution improved my situation a little bit.

Comment: This works for TL-WN822N(US) Ver 5.0 on Ubuntu 20.04. Compiles without errors Ensure that the GCC version is the same as the version that the kernel is compiled in. Use cat /proc/version to check. However the speed I get is 50 Mbps. The wired connection gives me 150Mbps.

Answer (score 2):

Ok here is an answer but you are not going to like it.

First, [this link](https://www.tp-link.com/us/download/TL-WN822N_V5.html#Driver) says: `Operating System: Linux (kernel 2.6.24 ~ <4.9.60)` and Ubuntu 18.04 has a kernel above that revision.

[image]

Second, the missing dependencies such as `libelf-dev` is not related to the aforementioned part. That's related strictly to your system config.

Third, I downloaded the driver myself as my system meets all dependencies so I gave it a go at compiling it regardless the fact that my system too uses kernel revision above the one suggested as "compatible". The first error I got was (no missing dependencies):

```
osdep_service_linux.h:299:8: error: ‘_timer {aka struct timer_list}’ has no member named ‘data’
  ptimer->data = (unsigned long)cntx;
```

That alone is a good enough sign to indicate that the new kernel has removed this member. Nonetheless, I kept going and I commented that line out (really bad idea, **don't ever do this but I am in a VM so I don't care if I lose any data in it**, but anyway I just wanted to see how far I will go...). I really wanted to compile that thing and see what happens so here is my mod:

[image]

The second error I got was:

```
osdep_service_linux.h:300:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer’; did you mean ‘_init_timer’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  init_timer(ptimer);
```

I fixed this by adding `EXTRA_CFLAGS += -Wno-implicit-function-declaration` on line 17 in the Makefile. Time to run another: `make` and what do you know, it actually compiled, more after this output:

```
marko @ marko-P7xxDM2-G  ~/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047
└─ $ make
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-43-generic/build M=/home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-43-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_cmd.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_security.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_debug.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_io.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_ioctl_query.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_ioctl_set.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_ieee80211.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_mlme.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_mlme_ext.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_mi.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_wlan_util.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_vht.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_pwrctrl.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_rf.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_recv.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_sta_mgt.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_ap.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_xmit.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_p2p.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_rson.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_tdls.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_br_ext.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_iol.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_sreset.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_btcoex_wifionly.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_btcoex.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_beamforming.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_odm.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/efuse/rtw_efuse.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/os_dep/osdep_service.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/os_dep/linux/usb_intf.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/os_dep/linux/usb_ops_linux.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/os_dep/linux/ioctl_linux.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/os_dep/linux/xmit_linux.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/os_dep/linux/mlme_linux.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/os_dep/linux/recv_linux.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/os_dep/linux/rtw_cfgvendor.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/os_dep/linux/wifi_regd.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/os_dep/linux/rtw_proc.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/os_dep/linux/ioctl_mp.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/hal_intf.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/hal_com.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/hal_com_phycfg.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/hal_phy.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/hal_dm.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/hal_dm_acs.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/hal_btcoex_wifionly.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/hal_btcoex.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/hal_mp.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/hal_mcc.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/hal_hci/hal_usb.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/led/hal_usb_led.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/HalPwrSeqCmd.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/rtl8192e/Hal8192EPwrSeq.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/rtl8192e/rtl8192e_xmit.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/rtl8192e/rtl8192e_sreset.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/rtl8192e/rtl8192e_hal_init.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/rtl8192e/rtl8192e_phycfg.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/rtl8192e/rtl8192e_rf6052.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/rtl8192e/rtl8192e_dm.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/rtl8192e/rtl8192e_rxdesc.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/rtl8192e/rtl8192e_cmd.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/rtl8192e/hal8192e_fw.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/rtl8192e/usb/usb_halinit.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/rtl8192e/usb/rtl8192eu_led.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/rtl8192e/usb/rtl8192eu_xmit.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/rtl8192e/usb/rtl8192eu_recv.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/rtl8192e/usb/usb_ops_linux.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/efuse/rtl8192e/HalEfuseMask8192E_USB.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/phydm_debug.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/phydm_antdiv.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/phydm_soml.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/phydm_smt_ant.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/phydm_antdect.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/phydm_interface.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/phydm_phystatus.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/phydm_hwconfig.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/phydm.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/phydm_dig.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/phydm_pathdiv.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/phydm_rainfo.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/phydm_dynamictxpower.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/phydm_adaptivity.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/phydm_cfotracking.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/phydm_noisemonitor.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/phydm_acs.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/phydm_beamforming.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/phydm_dfs.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/txbf/halcomtxbf.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/txbf/haltxbfinterface.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/txbf/phydm_hal_txbf_api.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/phydm_adc_sampling.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/phydm_ccx.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/phydm_psd.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/phydm_primary_cca.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/phydm_cck_pd.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/phydm_rssi_monitor.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/phydm_auto_dbg.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/phydm_math_lib.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/phydm_api.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/phydm_pow_train.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/halrf/halrf.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/halrf/halphyrf_ce.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/halrf/halrf_powertracking_ce.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/halrf/halrf_powertracking.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/halrf/halrf_kfree.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/rtl8192e/halhwimg8192e_mac.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/rtl8192e/halhwimg8192e_bb.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/rtl8192e/halhwimg8192e_rf.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/halrf/rtl8192e/halrf_8192e_ce.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/rtl8192e/phydm_regconfig8192e.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/phydm/rtl8192e/phydm_rtl8192e.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/btc/halbtc8723bwifionly.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/btc/halbtc8822bwifionly.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/btc/halbtc8821cwifionly.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/btc/halbtc8192e1ant.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/btc/halbtc8192e2ant.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/btc/halbtc8723b1ant.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/btc/halbtc8723b2ant.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/btc/halbtc8812a1ant.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/btc/halbtc8812a2ant.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/btc/halbtc8821a1ant.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/btc/halbtc8821a2ant.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/btc/halbtc8703b1ant.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/btc/halbtc8723d1ant.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/btc/halbtc8723d2ant.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/btc/halbtc8822b1ant.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/btc/halbtc8822b2ant.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/btc/halbtc8821c1ant.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/hal/btc/halbtc8821c2ant.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/platform/platform_ops.o
  CC [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_mp.o
  LD [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/8192eu.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
WARNING: "init_timer" [/home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/8192eu.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "__vfs_read" [/home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/8192eu.ko] undefined!
  CC      /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/8192eu.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/marko/Desktop/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/8192eu.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-43-generic'
```

Let's do a `ls *.ko` and we have ourselves a freshly compiled `8192eu.ko`

Let's see what it is:

`8192eu.ko: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), BuildID[sha1]=a4eae30125a8c332ccb8da9a86eebbe42be8ef57, not stripped`

Right, the manual says:

[image]
Ok then :) fingers crossed:

`insmod: ERROR: could not insert module 8192eu.ko: Unknown symbol in module`

So, what did we learn here? It won't load hence for the linux kernel version compatibility. Something has been removed from the newer kernel revisions that make the current code base incompatible.

I really hope you get it running somehow. What I have done above is the most I can do right now.

Comment: thank you! while it means i cant use it i guess ill just have to wait and hope for something to come along. i greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: No problems, also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/424823/tp-link-tl-wn822n-wifi-dongle-under-linux, it may help you. There appears to be an alternative driver which might work. I haven't tested it. Read the answer in that thread.

Comment: @suzumetin if it is actually a rtl8192eu chipset, there are alternative source code on github that do work, like the one mentioned in marko's other answer

Comment: Awesome TP-Link drivers support...